# Can I create a git hook that runs a script based on the tags for the commits being pushed?

Tags: git

I am trying to create a git hook such that when a user pushes it will take information about the tags attached to the commits and create an archive with the same name as the tag. I really only need to know if it is possible to use a pre-push hook for this and how to determine the information I need for the script specifically how to reference individual commits and their tags. Thanks!

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64564810/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+%22pre-push%22+tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious, I had finally learned that the references to commits and tags are passed through the stdin rather than the program arguments as I had previously thought, so when you read from stdin you get something like:
`refs/heads/main SHA-1 refs/heads/main SHA-1 refs/tags/v4.0 SHA-1 refs/tags/v4.0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`